# Can we somehow restrict automatic bumping of old questions to the front page?

Tags: discussion

It has become a quite frequent situation for me that I start typing an answer to a question on the front page only to realize after the first few lines (if I'm attentive enough) that it is a bump from some year in the distant past asked by a person who is, most likely, no longer interested, if still staying here at all. Checking the timestamp on every post is, of course, not too hard, but it is not what I would call my "knee reflex" yet. So I wonder if this bumping as it is now really seems to make sense to other people, and if not whether we can make it happen less often or in some more reasonable fashion.

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213468/why-do-people-answer-old-questions.

Comment: Also related, on Meta SE: [Which sites impose limits on Community bumps, and what are those limits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350958)

Answer (score 3):

At the top, do you have newest or active selected (or something else)? I have newest, and this doesn't happen to me. You can look at the 'filter' to get more of a sense of how this works.

[While playing with this setting, I left it on active by accident, and did almost exactly what you do. I was reading a question from 5 years ago, thinking it was new!]